# No resource identifier found for attribute 'tabIndicatorColor' in package 'Autorizador.Android' Autorizador.Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Tive vários erros, que fui eliminando, com a instalação dos pacotes. Porém esse três ainda não consegui eliminar. O interessante é que estava funcionando tudo e do nada, fui dar um build e começou a dar muitos erros. Eliminei alguns, mas esses não sei como fazer ou o que fazer. Esse é meu Tabbar.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

O package config do projeto Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.CSharp" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XmlDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.270" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
</packages>
```

Na descrição do erro é na linha 2. E a linha 2 é essa:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: Diz que o elemento `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` não foi declarado. Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi adicionando algumas referências. O que acontece é que eu não sabia quais eram, então fiz assim. Criei outro projeto da mesma forma, vi quais eram as `DLL's` e peguei o projeto com problemas e fui adicionando conforme o outro projeto. Deixei igual e isso resolveu. Só não entendi o porquê do erro, se estava funcionando e duas horas depois, fui rodar e começou a dar esse pau.